# ansible vsphere facts for using on multiple roles

Tags: ansible, role

I have a questions.

so basicly i have a playbook that will run 2 roles.
first role will connect to VMware vCenter via pysphere plugin and create a virtual machine, then "learn" its MAC address by "gathering facts" about it.
(2 tasks, one creates a VM, another gathers facts).

so that i can "debug" and actually see that newly created VM's MAC.

the second part of my playbook is to run another role which would connect to another server and enter some cobbler commands via "shell" module of ansible to create a cobbler profile for installation.

what i want to achieve is to be able to create a vm and create a cobbler installation profile..

the missing part here is of course the VM's MAC address.. (becouse its required by cobbler).

and i was not able to make "fact/variable" of that MAC from first role to be available in second role..

any ideas ? :)

tried to use fact_caching with json.. didnt help, or i did something wrong...

thanx alot!!

Comment: If you can run setup on that new VM the MAC address will be available at: `ansible_<IFNAME>.macaddress` ( You can test what `Gathering facts` does by running `ansible -vvi /path/to/inventory <yourhost> -m setup` )

Comment: i cannot run setup on this new VM since it doesnt "exist" yet..
Its created on vCenter by ansible, but not powered on yet since i need its MAC to power on..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set_fact` to set facts and use them later even between hosts.
This example generates random string (assume that it is a VM's MAC in your example) and use it later on another server:

```
- hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - shell: date | md5sum | head -c 8
      register: random_string_cmd
    - set_fact:
        random_string: "{{ random_string_cmd.stdout }}"

- hosts: host2
  tasks:
    - shell: echo "The random string generated on previous server is {{ hostvars['host1']['random_string'] }}"
```

You can use `set_fact` inside roles as well.